# PHP Serial port communication won't give read output

Tags: php, serial-port

I want to read out a QR reader with PHP. I used the library: https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial to setup communication with a serial port. The device is connected but won't read output. Below my code.

```
<?php
include 'src/PhpSerial.php';


function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());

    return ((float) $usec + (float) $sec);
}
// Let's start the class
$serial = new PhpSerial;

// First we must specify the device. This works on both linux and windows (if
// your linux serial device is /dev/ttyS0 for COM1, etc)

// We can change the baud rate, parity, length, stop bits, flow control
$serial->deviceSet("COM1");
$serial->confBaudRate(115200);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->confFlowControl("none");

// Then we need to open it
$serial->deviceOpen();

$read = '';
$theResult = '';
$start = microtime_float();
 // To write into
 // Or to read from
while ( ($read == '') && (microtime_float() <= $start + 2) ) {
    $read = $serial->readPort();
    if ($read != '') {
        $theResult .= $read;
        $read = '';
    }
}
$serial->deviceClose();
// If you want to change the configuration, the device must be closed

// We can change the baud rate

// etc...
//
//
/* Notes from Jim :
> Also, one last thing that would be good to document, maybe in example.php:
>  The actual device to be opened caused me a lot of confusion, I was
> attempting to open a tty.* device on my system and was having no luck at
> all, until I found that I should actually be opening a cu.* device instead!
>  The following link was very helpful in figuring this out, my USB/Serial
> adapter (as most probably do) lacked DTR, so trying to use the tty.* device
> just caused the code to hang and never return, it took a lot of googling to
> realize what was going wrong and how to fix it.
>
> http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2009/Nov/msg00099.html

Riz comment : I've definately had a device that didn't work well when using cu., but worked fine with tty. Either way, a good thing to note and keep for reference when debugging.
 */
```

At first I thought the problem was in the serial port configuration. But i double checkt everything and it's setup correctly. If i open the serial port with an serial port reader program "Hercules" then it reads a value if i scan an qr code.

Comment: I can't help you on the PHP side, but is there a reason you can't just use a normal scanner on the client side that is effectively just a keyboard and send that data over HTTP to the server?

Comment: Is the scanner on the server ?  If not, then this code can not work.

Comment: @RohitGupta Scanner is on the server.